# optimize adding column to CSV file (~300GB) with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, optimization

I want to add a column to CSV file, which is the difference of two other columns of the same file, I use Python (pandas) to do that and this is what I do:

```
import pandas as pd
row = ['times1','times2']
for df1 in pd.read_csv('C:/SET/parti_no_diff.CSV',skipinitialspace=True, usecols=row, chunksize=10**7):
    df1['time_difference'] = (df1['times2'].astype('datetime64[s]')-df1['times1'].astype('datetime64[s]')).abs()
    df1.to_csv('E:/SET/parti_with_diff_seconds.csv',mode='a')
```

I use a machine with 12GB RAM, and external hard disk of 2TB (5200RPM) (the input are not on the same hard disk as output), the program take more than 24h, how can I optimize it?

Comment: Why are you reading the csv file in a for-loop?

Comment: have you considered using a database for a file this large

Comment: @DavidDR i'm reading it in for loop because it has a size of 300gb so it can't fit in the memory

Comment: Please stick to the internationally agreed SI units system - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units Please use **B** for **bytes** and **b** for **bits**, so one megabyte is 1MB, one gigabyte is 1GB (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte), one gigabit is 1Gb (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit), and if you have to refer to a milllibit for some reason that would be 1mb. Thank you.

Comment: @Mark Setchell thank you for the remarks

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, Python's built in functionality to read and write text files is optimal for this.  Read in a single line at a time to a list, add your extra column, then append it to the output text file.

Read in a single line at a time, modify it however you want, then append it to the output file.  It'll happen faster than you think.  You can use something like tqdm to monitor progress.

Something like:

```
import csv
from tqdm import tqdm
with open('myfile.txt', newline='') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f)
     for row in tqdm(reader):
          row.append('new_column')
          with open('output.csv', 'a') as outfile:
               outfile.write(row)
```

Comment: I did like you said, but it still not fast enough, i changed the code little bit (i opened the output.csv once with the input), but it still take lot of time, i'm thinking of modifying the file input itself to benefit of time of copying data from input to output file, but how can i do that, and i wonder if there is a possibility of working with the files opened in binary(it should be faster)